# Dynamic Model in MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Our Application is developed using MVC 4.0. We have a MVC view that's is attached to Dynamic Model.(@model  dynamic)

When we submit the view , the dynamic model is posted as an object to Submit Action. Inside Submit Action, we are trying to capture this dynamic model and cast to a typed model. But it's not working, we tried all suggestions provided online but still no luck.

**MVC View -->** Attached to dynamic model (@model dynamic)
**On Submit click --->** Call Submit Action Result Method
**Submit Action Result --->** Catch the posted dynamic model and cast it to    typed model. Let's say we have a typed model call product.cs. All we need to do is cast the posted dynamic model to product.cs in the submit action result!!!

Comment: By "posted dynamic model" do you mean, that your `Submit` action accepts an argument of type `dynamic`?

Comment: On post, you probably can't just type cast it - but you could build an instance of the model you want and then  copy over the properties of what was posted as dynamic to the new model and use it that way.

Comment: Yes my submit action has an argument of type dynamic..

Comment: Instead of casting dynamic argument to concrete type try to change Sumbit action argument to concrete type.

Comment: I've 6 different concrete type models and my view can POST any one at a time. Are you asking to have all 6 types as arguments to my submit action and work with one type which is not null ?

Comment: Could they all inherit the same interface and then you could accept interface in the action method?